# What's up with all the jellyfish?

Tags: plot-explanation, ad-vitam

Several times within the first couple episodes of *Ad Vitam* there are jellyfish. At the beginning of the first episode someone was dressed up as a huge jellyfish, and then later on Christa's parents are shown having a pet jellyfish. (There are also a couple other instances of jellyfish but those mentioned are the two major ones.)

So, what's the significance of a jellyfish? AFAIK they've not talked or hinted about it at all (and I'm on the third episode now and it doesn't seem like they're going to).

Comment: If I recall, the scientific breakthrough that enables the regenaration  process came from research on jellyfish. I think this gets explained in a later episode. Just a comment as I don't have the detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, what's the significance of a jellyfish?

#### The jellyfish is the source of the research that led to humans being able to regenerate.

When Darius and his partner Lesky arrive at Musee Stern in S01E03, Lesky watches a video that explains it all:

> VIDEO NARRATION: The *Turinapsis Idraecula* was first described almost 80 years ago by Augustus and Paula Stern, two biologists specializing in the biotopes of the Miocene. They were the first to notice its infinite faculty for regeneration. **The jellyfish they observed were able to block the ageing process...**

Shortly after that moment, the 'ageless' jellyfish is shown --

[image]